# Question on positive definite block matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices

Suppose that we have symmetric positive definite matrices $A,B,D \in R^{n \times n}$.
Further, we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}A&C\\C^T &B \end{bmatrix} > 0$$
and also
$$\begin{bmatrix}A B^{-1} A &C\\C^T & B A^{-1} B \end{bmatrix} > 0$$ holds.

Does anyone knows whether 
$$\begin{bmatrix}(A+D) (B+D)^{-1} (A+D) & C+D\\C^T +D & (B+D) (A+D)^{-1} (B+D) \end{bmatrix} > 0$$
holds? Thank you!

Comment: Have you done any computer experiment to see that if this conjecture is convincing or not?

Comment: I did some tests and it seems to work, but I do not know how to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conjecture is wrong. It should be easy to generate a random counterexample using a computer. E.g. I obtained the followings:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}A&C\\ C^T&B\end{bmatrix}=
\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
7&1&0&0\\ 1&1&0&2\\ \hline 0&0&3&1\\ 0&2&1&7
\end{array}\right],
\ D=\begin{bmatrix}5&-3\\ -3&3\end{bmatrix}.
$$
you may verify that $A,B,D$ as well as the first two block matrices in your question are positive definite, but the last block matrix in your question has a negative eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks! I made a mistake in the experiments.